# Plotting gams using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I would like to plot a GAM using ggplot. It works with one variable but not with two. 
Does anyone have any idea how to solve that?

I used ggplot for one variable and it worked, adding a second variable and changing the formula didn't give me a plot but neither an error message.

This is a data sample (dataframe called SSTAall):

```
Date      Diff   Perc   clima.temp
12.4.18   1.41   20.8   13.8
13.4.18   2.09   22.9   13.2
14.4.18   0.81   12.4   13.4
```

This worked for one variable:

```
ggplot(SSTAall, aes(SSTAall$Diff, SSTAall$Perc)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~s(x))
```

It didn't work for two variables:

```
ggplot(( aes(SSTAall$Diff + s(SSTAall$clima.temp), SSTAall$Perc)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ x+s(x)))
```

Comment: DId it not give you any plot or only the points?

Comment: please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No sure what you are trying to achieve with : ```SSTAall$Diff + s(SSTAall$clima.temp)```. Is ```s()``` from the mgcv package ? How would your expected output look like ?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach did not give me anything

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend that you don't do this; fit your GAM in *mgcv* and then plot features of that fitted model alongside the relevant data using *ggplot2*. To that end, you might find the *gratia* pkg helpful in providing functions to process *mgcv* models into objects amenable to plotting with `ggplot()`.